# get all the time in 15 minutes interval since last 4 hours

Tags: perl, unix

I need all the time  in 15 minutes intervals since  last 4 hours till now
for example current time is `15:30:00`
then I need time like

```
2014-08-01 11:30:00 
2014-08-01 11:45:00
2014-08-01 12:00:00
2014-08-01 12:15:00
2014-08-01 12:30:00
....
2014-08-01 15:30:00
```

Total 16 records (15 minutes interval for 4 hours 4 * 4)

I tried with

```
date --date="2014-08-01 15:30:00  4hours  ago" +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

Comment: The number of times in that list is seventeen, not sixteen. Are you sure you want that? Suppose the time was 15:44, do you still want those seventeen times? 11:30 would be 4hours 14 minutes ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use strict; use warnings;

my $time = time();
my $period = 15*60; # 15 minutes
for ( my $t = $time -16*$period; $t<=$time; $t+=$period) {
  my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst)=localtime($t);
  printf "%d-%02d-%02d %2d:%02d:%02d\n", $year+1900, $mon+1, $mday, $hour, $min, $sec;
}
```

Simpler:

```
use strict; use warnings;

use POSIX qw( strftime );

my $time = time();
my $period = 15*60; # 15 minutes
for ( my $t = $time -16*$period; $t<=$time; $t+=$period) {
  print strftime "%Y-%m-%d %H:$M:%S\n", localtime($t);
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this? Did you notice that it prints times on 1st January 2014?

Comment: 2014-01-01 14:57:05
2014-01-01 15:12:05
2014-01-01 15:27:05
2014-01-01 15:42:05
2014-01-01 15:57:05
2014-01-01 16:12:05
2014-01-01 16:27:05
2014-01-01 16:42:05
2014-01-01 16:57:05
2014-01-01 17:12:05
2014-01-01 17:27:05
2014-01-01 17:42:05
2014-01-01 17:57:05
2014-01-01 18:12:05
2014-01-01 18:27:05
2014-01-01 18:42:05
2014-01-01 18:57:05

Comment: @ikegami I personally prefer to avoiding importing modules for single _trivial_ task.

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;` - these are pragmas not modules.  IMHO these two  should be used during development and test and MAY be removed in the final stable version.

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip: Your thinking is backward and I would like to see you defend it. Handling date/time values is far from trivial, and even if you can get it right then you have only recreated functionality that has already been written. As for `strict` and `warnings`, you have done the community a dangerous disservice by suggesting that they may be removed. If you want no warning or information about bugs that appear in the field then by all means go ahead, but you will be working blind with code that may have been running for days before a symptom shows up.

Comment: @Borodin Date&time formats: my suggestion to avoid specialized modules **is limited to trivial cases**. strict&warnings: I DO NOT remove them myself but it may be not so bad idea in some very specific cases of stable and tested code in environments with low resources. So it is use strict&warnings (**almost**) always.

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip: Your choice to avoid a module in this case, which I presume you regard as trivial, resulted in a bug that was less likely to have occurred if you had used already written and tested software. As for removing `strict` and `warnings` *"in some very specific cases of stable and tested code in environments with low resources"* I would like to see you back that up with figures that show that their use makes a significant difference to processor or memory usage. The best advice by far is to `use strict` and `use warnings` *always*, and muddying the waters does no one any good.

Answer (score 0):

This should suit you. It prints seventeen date/times ending with the latest multiple of 15 minutes at or before the current time. It uses [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time::Piece), which is a core module and should already be installed on your system.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds qw/ ONE_MINUTE /;

my $interval = ONE_MINUTE * 15;
my $now = localtime;
my $second_of_hour = $now->minute * ONE_MINUTE + $now->second;

my $final = $now - $second_of_hour % $interval;

for my $n (-16 .. 0) {
  my $moment = $final + $n * $interval;
  say $moment->datetime =~ tr/T/ /r;
}
```

**output**

```
2014-08-01 08:15:00
2014-08-01 08:30:00
2014-08-01 08:45:00
2014-08-01 09:00:00
2014-08-01 09:15:00
2014-08-01 09:30:00
2014-08-01 09:45:00
2014-08-01 10:00:00
2014-08-01 10:15:00
2014-08-01 10:30:00
2014-08-01 10:45:00
2014-08-01 11:00:00
2014-08-01 11:15:00
2014-08-01 11:30:00
2014-08-01 11:45:00
2014-08-01 12:00:00
2014-08-01 12:15:00
```